# ¿Cómo dar formato a una cadena en la salida?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Por ejemplo:

```
palabra = input('escribe una palabra:') 
print('la palabra que ingrasaste: ',palabra,' tiene 4 letras.')
```

Output que tengo: la palabra que ingrasaste: hola tiene 4 letras.

Output que quiero: la palabra que ingrasaste: 'hola' tiene 4 letras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya que la palabra en cuestión la ha introducido el usuario a través de `input()`, no tenemos la posibilidad indicada por @shadow que tendríamos si la variable la inicializáramos por programa.

No obstante, puedes usar las funciones de formato de cadenas, o el operador `%` de iterpolación de cadenas, o una "f-string", para meter el valor de una variable dentro de una "plantilla" que indica cómo debe salir. Ya de paso, el 4 de "4 letras" también puede ser calculado, para que no sea siempre 4 sino la verdadera longitud de lo que el usuario ingresó.

Esta sería la sintaxis:

- Interpolación de cadenas (`%`, válido en todas las versiones de python, pero se considera hoy día desaconsejado):

  ```
  print("la palabra que ingresaste: '%s' tiene %d letras" % (palabra, len(palabra)))
  ```

  Como ves, en el lugar donde queremos que aparezca una variable usamos `%` y una letra que representa el tipo de la variable. `%s` para cadenas, `%d` para enteros. Después a la "plantilla" se le aplica el operador `%` con una tupla que tiene los valores a sustituir.
- Formato de cadenas (`str.format()`, disponible a partir de python 2.6 es el método más recomendado hoy día (a menos que tengas python 3.6+)

  ```
  print("la palabra que ingresaste: '{}' tiene {} letras".format(palabra, len(palabra)))
  ```

  Como ves aquí, la "plantilla" usa ahora `{}` como indicador de los lugares donde deben aparecer los valores de las variables. Se pueden especificar [muchas opciones](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) dentro de esas llaves para especificar el tipo, el número de caracteres que queremos que ocupe en el resultado, etc. Pero dejando simplemente `{}` es suficiente para la mayoría de los casos. La "plantilla" no es más que una cadena python, y a partir de python 2.6 las cadenas tienen el método `str.format()` que permite transformarlas en otra cadena expandiendo los lugares donde están esas llaves según los valores de las variables que pasemos como parámetro.
- F-strings. Esto es nuevo en python 3.6 y el método favorito de muchos, siempre que dispongas de esta versión de python.

  ```
  print(f"la palabra que ingresaste '{palabra}' tiene {len(palabra)} letras")
  ```

  Como ves en este caso, una f-string es una "plantilla" dentro de la cual pueden aparecer entre llaves nombres de variables o incluso expresiones como `len(palabra)` y python expandirá la cadena computando los valores de las expresiones y variables y sustituyéndolos en la cadena.

  Se diferencian de una cadena normal en que tienen una `f` delante de las comillas.

En cualquiera de los ejemplos anteriores puedes cambiar las comillas simples por dobles y viceversa, si quieres que el resultado del print muestre la palabra entre comillas dobles. Por ejemplo:

```
print('la palabra que ingresaste: "{}" tiene {} letras'.format(palabra, len(palabra)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo simplemente haría lo siguiente:

La palabra *Hola* la meto en un orden de comillas dobles y por dentro comillas simples, envolviendo la palabra -> `"'Hola'"`

Como observas en este punto como las comillas dobles envuelven al contenido, el intérprete lee todo lo que esta por dentro y lo vuelca en pantalla

De modo tal que tu código debería quedar:

```
palabra = "'hola'" 

print('la palabra que ingrasaste: ',palabra,' tiene 4 letras.')
```

Y la salida debería de ser:

```
la palabra que ingrasaste: 'hola' tiene 4 letras.
```